# Images are not loading on the page but links work on inspect element in browser

Tags: reactjs, image

I have an issue with my site made with reactJs.
The imageUrls are good, I can see them in the inspect element but they are not visible on the page. And that is strange because they are getting from firebase to the element but somehow they are not visible. I added the component code and style component for the images.
Any ideas why?

GitHub link: https://github.com/dieterhalosta/flower_time

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addItem} from '../../redux/cart/cart.actions';
import {
    CollectionItemContainer,
    CollectionFooterContainer,
    AddButton,
    BackgroundImage,
    NameContainer,
    PriceContainer
  } from './collection-item.style';

const CollectionItem = ({item, addItem}) => {
    const {name, price, imageUrl} = item;

    return (
        <CollectionItemContainer>
            <BackgroundImage className='image' imageUrl={imageUrl}/>
            <CollectionFooterContainer>
                <NameContainer>{name}</NameContainer>
                <PriceContainer>{price}</PriceContainer>
            </CollectionFooterContainer>
            <AddButton onClick={() => addItem(item)} inverted>
                Add to cart
            </AddButton>
        </CollectionItemContainer>
)};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addItem: item => dispatch(addItem(item))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CollectionItem);

export const BackgroundImage = styled.div`
      width: 100%;
      height: 95%
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      background-image: ${({ imageUrl }) => `url(${imageUrl})`};      
`;
```

[image: 1]

Comment: It is really difficult to answer based on limited information you provided, but If you want to load some images in some control, You need to set that image as a source to that particular control. As you have not shared any code, It is difficult to verify whether that is the issue or something else.
Please post your code here rather than posting only error image.

Comment: Please add your code in code block and the produced HTML. Without this it is impossible to say is the error in your code of at the network level. Also you can try to execute it in some JS fiddle to exclude network issues.

Comment: your div needs height n width, right now it's 0x0 pixels, because there is no content inside it. also prefer img tag for images